# Python3 - Extract the text from a bs4.element.Tag and add to a dictonary

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a website which returns a bs4.element.Tag similar to the following:

```
<span class="attributes-value"> 
        <span class="four-door">four door</span>
        <span class="inline-4-engine">inline 4 engine</span>
        <span class="24-gallons-per-mile">24 gallons per mile</span>
</span>
```

I am trying to extract just the text from this block and add it to a dictionary. All of the examples that I am seeing on the forum include some sort of common element like an 'id' or similar. I am not an html guy so i may be using incorrect terms.

What I would like to do is get the text ("four door", "v6 engine", etc) and add them as values to a dictionary with the key being a pre-designated variable of car_model.

```
cars = {'528i':['four door', 'inline 4 engine']}
```

I cant figure out a universal way to pull out the text because there may be more or fewer span classes with different text. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through all the elements by selector and extract text value from these elements.

A selector is a specific path to the element you want. In my case, the selector is `.attributes-value span`, where `.attributes-value` allows you to access the class, and `span` allows you to access the tags within that class.

The [`get_text()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) retrieves the content between the opening and closing tags. This is exactly what you need.

I also recommend using [`lxml`](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/) because it will speed up your code.

The full code is attached below:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

html = '''
<span class="attributes-value"> 
        <span class="four-door">four door</span>
        <span class="inline-4-engine">inline 4 engine</span>
        <span class="24-gallons-per-mile">24 gallons per mile</span>
</span>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

cars = {
    '528i': []
}

for span in soup.select(".attributes-value span"):
    cars['528i'].append(span.get_text())

print(cars)
```

Output:

```
{'528i': ['four door', 'inline 4 engine', '24 gallons per mile']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```py
out = defaultdict(list)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
for tag in soup.select(".attributes-value span"):
   out["528i"].append(tag.text)

print(dict(out))
```

Prints:

```
{'528i': ['four door', 'inline 4 engine', '24 gallons per mile']}
```